# EntityFramework exception: How can i see the real query

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

Sometimes i have an EntityFramework exception where calling SaveChanges.
I see this kind of message: "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."
I have logged the stack trace, the inner exception and stuff but there is no clear explanation of the problem. I would like to see the real query (it is a mysql database), with the parameters. Do you know how i can see or log the real query ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use DbEntityValidationException handler which will let you know what was wrong precisely.

```
try{

  //Your code here
 }

catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
{
  var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
    .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
    .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);
   var fullMessageError = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);
   var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, "Exact Message " +   fullMessageError);


}
catch (Exception ex)
{
//General Exception here
}
```

Comment: Thanks but DbEntityValidationException is not fired

Answer (score 0):

You can set log property of dbContext.Database and log the actual queries generated by EF.

```
using (var context = new MyDBContext()) 
{ 
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write;  // This is where you setup where to log queries

    // Your code here... 
}
```

There is a detailed documentation on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx